# NHibernate LINQ Join 2 queries to retrieve stocks with 4 recent vendors

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I have to retrieve stocks and recent 4 vendors. I got stock in one list. Got purchase order with vendors in another list. Want to get a merge result of all stocks with their recent 4 vendors in purchasing if any. I am not good with LINQ and this is NHibernate as well

This is my updated work. Seeking how to write third LINQ sql to get this.

```
       IEnumerable<StockDetailReportModal> stockDetail = Session.Query<Stock>()
            .Where(predicate)
            .ToList()
            .Select(n => new StockDetailReportModal
            {
                Id = n.Id,
                Number = n.Number,
                PaddedNumber = n.PaddedNumber,
                Buyer = n.Buyer == null ? string.Empty : n.Buyer.FullName,
                SalesTaxCode = n.SalesTaxCode == null ? null : n.SalesTaxCode.Code,
                PurchasingUnitOfMeasure = n.PurchasingUnitOfMeasure,
                InventoryUnitOfMeasure = n.InventoryUnitOfMeasure,
                CatalogueDescription = n.CatalogueDescription,
                BrandDescription = n.BrandDescription,
                EconomicOrderQuantity = n.EconomicOrderQuantity,
                LastYearPurchasePrice = n.LastYearPurchasePrice,
                ThisYearIssuePrice = n.ThisYearIssuePrice,
                NextYearIssuePrice = n.NextYearIssuePrice,
                Description = n.StockCommodityCode == null ? string.Empty : n.StockCommodityCode.Code + "-" + n.StockCommodityCode.Description,
            }).OrderBy(o => o.VendorNumber);

        var vendorhistoryList = Session.Query<PurchaseOrderLineItem>()
            .Where(pOpredicate)
            .Where(p => p.Stock.Number != null)
            .ToList()
            .Select(c => new
            {
                stockId = c.Id,
                LastPurchaseDate = c.PurchaseOrder.OrderDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
                VendorNumber = c.PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderVendor.Vendor.Number,
                LastPurchasePrice = c.UnitPrice,
                LastTransactionDate =
                    c.LastTransactionDate != null ? c.LastTransactionDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") : null,
                LeadTimeDays = GetDays(c.PurchaseOrder.OrderDate, c.LastTransactionDate),
            }).GroupBy(d => d.VendorNumber).Select(gpo => gpo
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastPurchaseDate)
                .Take(4));
```

My problem starts here when vendorhistoryList object does not show any property. What I am doing wrong here? I am trying to left join stockDetail with vendorhistoryList on stock.id with 1 or more stock rows with upto 4 recent vendors. Please suggest what should I do?

Here is the last part I need.

```
      var stockdetailResult = from sd in stockDetail
            join vh in vendorhistoryList on sd.Id equals vh.Id into sv
            from vs in sv.DefaultIfEmpty() ???
          .select ( c=> c.fields1....c.fields2...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very similar problem I was facing so just answered to that question which can be applied here as well. Attaching a link of that question.

[Product with last 4 vendors on transaction date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113310/product-with-last-4-vendors-on-transaction-date)