# Product with last 4 vendors on transaction date

Tags: nhibernate, subquery, queryover, correlated-subquery

Hi I have this sql and have to translate into NHibernate QueryOver

```
SELECT S.Number, S.Description, S.BrandDescription, subquery.vendornumber, subquery.vendorname
FROM Stocks.Stock S left join 
                    (select vendorNumber, VendorName, POLID, LastTransactionDate from
                        (
                        SELECT top 4 v.Number vendorNumber, v.Name VendorName, PLL.Id POLID, max(por.TransactionDate) as LastTransactionDate,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY v.Number ORDER BY max(por.TransactionDate) DESC) AS rk
                        FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderLineItem PLL 
                        inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrder po on PLL.PurchaseOrderId = po.Id
                        inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderVendor POV on po.Id = POV.PurchaseOrderId
                        inner join Purchasing.Vendor V on pov.VendorId =  v.Id
                        left outer join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderReceipt POR on PLL.Id = por.PurchaseOrderLineItemId
                        group by v.Number, v.Name,PLL.Id
                        order by LastTransactionDate desc
                        ) subquery
                        where subquery.rk = 1) B on PL.Id = b.POLID
```

Or just to explain it simply see its simplified version

```
Select * from master m
outer apply (select top 4 * From Details d where m.Id = d.Id order by someColumns desc)o
```

I think we cannot use subquery as derived table in nhibernate. If you have suggestions, please share.

Thanks

Comment: In a nutshwell, NHibernate FROM is defined by class/entity mapping, JOIN is defined by reference mapping. So the above SQL query won't work. The solution here is to: 1) Create View - and encapsulate all the complexity - map it as an Entity 2) use raw SQL query to get these data. Any other solution won't fit to ORM in common

Comment: Thanks @RadimKöhler for reply. I have done a stored procedure which is working fine but my boss say no to any thing outside NHibernate mapping entities due to security limitation. I was also trying to create two separate queryover results and combine or join to have this requirement.  Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: I would try to use either view which then could be mapped as an entity, or some "C#" combining - exactly as you said. But the point is, that such complex query as you have to create, is simply outside of abilities of the ORM world... sorry, to not have better answer ..

Comment: Thanks again. At-least I can show this reply to my boss and team who think that everything is possible in NHibernate and it is much easier than SQL. I am the only person here who can write complex SQLs and this is a big problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was keep working on this and found that it could be very difficult if want to do totally with QueryOver. I want to show how I did this.

First I took all the vendors with StockID to join with StockQuery later.

```
            var stockVendors =
            Session.QueryOver<Vendor>(() => V)
                .Left.JoinQueryOver(p => V.Stock, () => sstk)
                .Where(sstk.Number !=null)
                .OrderBy(Projections.Max(() => V.TransactionDate)).Desc()
                .ThenBy(() => sstk.Number).Asc()
                .ThenBy(() => sv.Number).Asc()
                .SelectList(
                    lst =>
                    lst.SelectGroup(() => V.Name).WithAlias(() => svhModal.VendorName)
                        .SelectGroup(() => V.Number).WithAlias(() => svhModal.VendorNumber)
                        .SelectGroup(() => sstk.Number).WithAlias(() => svhModal.StockNumber)
                        .Select(Projections.Max(() => V.TransactionDate)).WithAlias(() => svhModal.LastTransactionDate)
```

)
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean()).List();

Then select Stock only

```
var stockDetail = Session.QueryOver<Stock>(() => stk)
            .Where(soneCriteria)
            .SelectList(list => list
                .Select(() => stk.Id).WithAlias(() => sdrModal.Id)
                .Select(() => stk.Number).WithAlias(() => sdrModal.Number)
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<StockDetailReportModal>())
                    .List<StockDetailReportModal>();

 IList<StockVendor> vlst2 = null;
            IList<StockDetail> newStock = new List<StockDetail>();
```

> > Here starts two loops to fill List object with each stock and its 5 top vendors from vendors list. Loop from Stockdetail result from query and inside loop from vendor result filtered to outer loop stockid, get first 5 vendors only in loop, when done just return the result to report. Its working fine.

```
foreach (StockDetail ostk in stockDetail)
        {
            stkid = ostk.Number;
            vlst2 = (from v in stockVendors where v.StockNumber == stkid orderby v.LastTransactionDate descending select v).ToList<StockVendor>();

            vndrcnt = 0;
            stok = new StockDetail
            {
                Id = ostk.Id,
                Number = ostk.Number,
//// other fields too here
            };

            if (vlst2.Count() == 0)
            {
                newStock.Add(stok);
            }

            foreach (StockVendor vn in vlst2)
            {
                if (vndrcnt == 0)
                {
                    stok.VendorName = vn.VendorName;
                    stok.VendorNumber = vn.VendorNumber;
          // other fields here...
                    newStock.Add(stok);
                }
                else
                {
                    newStock.Add(new StockDetail
                    {
                        Id = ostk.Id,
                        Number = ostk.Number,
                        VendorName = vn.VendorName,
                        VendorNumber = vn.VendorNumber,
// adding vendor information in stock record.
                        });
                    }
                    vndrcnt++;
                    if (vndrcnt >= 4)
                        break;
                }
```

This solved my problem and achieved this after investigating many days. You may find better approach, so please share.